# Keras continuous training with DB

Tags: python, keras, data-science, lstm, tf.keras

I am new to Keras and still looking for ways for continuous training the model. Since my dataset is very large to store in memory, I am supposed to store in a DB (NoSql DB- MongoDb or HBase) and train records as batch wise. My model LSTM - multi input & outputs. How my current trainings and prediction are as following.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=in_dim, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(out_dim))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.summary()

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=100, batch_size=12, verbose=0)    
ypred = model.predict(xtest)
```

However, still I am looking for very clear and simple samples that shows how to feed batch wise records pulled from DB to train the model.

Comment: Your previous question look very similar and it was closed, this one also looks off-topic, you are asking for sample code which is off-topic here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is very large and cannot be stored in memory, then write a generator which generated a batch of data  at a time. You can then use `fit_generator` to train on the generator output. If you can code the generator in a way it can be pickled then you can use `use_multiprocessing` feature of the `fit_generator` to run the generator on multiple  processes and keep multiple batch ready which significantly reduces the disk I/O wait time.

#### Sample code

```
import keras
import numpy as np

# Dummy database class
class DB:
  def get_total_records_count(self):
    return 1e6
  
  def read_records_at(self, ids):
    X = np.random.randn(len(ids), 50)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 5, len(ids))
    return X, y

# Generator which generate a batch at a time
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
  def __init__(self, db, batch_size=32):
    self.db = db
    self.n = self.db.get_total_records_count()
    self.idx = np.arange(self.n)
    self.batch_size = batch_size

  def __len__(self):
    return int(np.floor(self.n / self.batch_size))

  # Generate a batch of (X, y)
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    idxs = self.idx[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
    return self.db.read_records_at(idxs)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, input_dim=(50)))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

df = DataGenerator(DB(), 4)
model.fit_generator(df)
```

Output

```
Epoch 1/1
250000/250000 [==============================] - 380s 2ms/step - loss: 7.1443
<keras.callbacks.callbacks.History at 0x7fa3ff150048>
```

Comment: Thanks mujjiga. The method 'read_records_at' should have a DB client and return the requested table rows. Isn't it? I will read more on Generators. May I know one more thing please? If this is going to happen infinite, then how can use the model for prediction ? I want to get the prediction with the latest model being trained ( may be after every 3 hrs). Should I stop the training completely or is there a way to get prediction asynchronously or in parallel ?

Comment: @you can't train it for every. Keep training on some data (train data) and evaluation of some data(val data). Check cross validation

Comment: I did initial validation with first sets of batches. This is for a real time app and I can get random predictions and validate later also. However, now predictions needs to be continued while training. Anyway, you mean that training should be stopped or completed, then only prediction can happen ? and no support from Keras for that ?

Comment: You can dump the weight of the model periodically after certain batches and have another program which picks up the latest model weights into a model and does the prediction. Basically one program for training and another for prediction using the first program weights.